# How to convert this MySQL query to a Django query?

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

I have a query like this:

```
select files_id, count(DISTINCT shared_user_id) FROM fileupload_share GROUP BY files_id;
```

which I want to convert in Django query. Tried like this:

```
count = Share.objects.filter(users_id=request.user.id).values_list('shared_user_id').distinct().count()
```

but doesn't give me a group by required output. I want the output to be returned in a list like

```
count = [1, 2, 3, 1]
```

models.py:

```
class Share(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    files = models.ForeignKey(File)
    shared_user_id = models.IntegerField()
    shared_date = models.TextField()

class File(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.TextField()
    time_overview = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    end_date = models.TextField()
    duration = models.TextField()
    size_overview = models.IntegerField()
    size = models.TextField()
    flag = models.TextField()
    flag_r = models.TextField()
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: this question is the same earlier question you have created

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't get the expected answer.

Comment: You know you can also fall back to raw sql https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Also, I already accepted the best SQL answer for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
files = File.objects.filter(users_id=request.user.id).annotate(count=Count('share__shared_user_id')
```

Then you should have

```
for f in files:
    print f.file_name, f.count
```

Comment: Thanks but how could I integrate with the File model. Generating file information and display the shared count to each file.

Comment: Updated my answer. I have not been able to test it so it could be errors in it.

Comment: It worked mate, I have another problem though. I want to find the username with whom the file is shared. How can I do that?